# perl: can a hash entry reference be used to delete from the hash?

Tags: perl, hash, filehandle

Here's some perl pseudo code for what I'm asking:

```
my %x;
# initialize %x

my $ref = whateverSyntacticSugarIsNeeded( $x{this}{hash}{is}{deep} );

# ...
# make use of $ref multiple times
# ...

delete $ref; # ideally, this would delete $x{this}{hash}{is}{deep}
```

... where the idea is to avoid use of `$x{this}{hash}{is}{deep}` more than is absolutely necessary.

I'm fairly sure this isn't possible and the least uses possible is 2 (the initial ref/copy of the value, then to delete the key/value pair from `%x`).  However, if I'm mistaken then feel free to correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want exactly. If

```
%x = ( very => { deep => { hash => { is => "here" } } } );
```

and you assign

```
$y = $x{very}{deep}{hash}{is}
```

then is's like writing

```
$y = 'here'
```

so you can't `delete $y`. You can, though,

```
$z = $x{very}{deep}{hash};
delete $z->{is};
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is just to reference the hash one level up.

This is especially true if you give the variable a semantically appropriate name (something other than ref):

```
my %x;
# initialize %x

my $ref = $x{this}{hash}{is};

# ...
# make use of $ref multiple times
# ...

delete $ref->{deep};
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl tracks whether or not a piece of memory is used by using a count to that piece of memory. If I did this:

```
my $ref->{this}->{is}->{a}->{deep} = "hash";
undef $ref;     # Note I use "undef" and not "delete"
```

I free up all of that memory. All of the hash references and the actual scalar that those hash references point to. That's because I have no further way of accessing that memory.

If I do something a bit simpler:

```
my %hash = ( one => 1, two => 2, ref => { three => 3, four => 4 }, five => 5 );
```

Note that `$hash{ref}` is a reference to another hash. If I did this:

```
my $ref = $hash{ref};
```

I now have two variables that can access that piece of memory. Doing this:

```
delete $hash{ref};
```

does not free up that memory because `$ref` still points to it. However, that hash reference is no longer in my `%hash` hash.

If I didn't delete `$hash{ref}`, but did this:

```
$ref->{seven} = 7;
```

I have changed `%hash` because `$ref` and `$hash{ref}` point to the same piece of memory: That same hash reference. Doing this:

```
delete $hash{ref}->{four};
```

or
    delete $ref->{four};

will both delete a particular entry in that hash reference.

We don't have to do something that complex either:

```
my %hash = ( one => 1, two => 2, three => 3 );
my $ref = \%hash;     #Creating a reference to that hash
delete $ref->{three};
```

This will delete $hash{three} since both are pointing to the same hash in memory. However,

```
undef $ref;
```

will not undefine `$hash` too.

I hope this covers your question. As long as there's another way to refer to a memory location, it's not freed in Perl. However, if you point a reference to a data structure, manipulating that data structure through the reference will manipulate that data structure referenced through an array or hash variable.